# Deciphering cypher text after breaking the RSA system

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

I already broke the RSA system and now have the following parameters:

$m = 536813567 = 8191 \cdot 65537,$

$e = 3602561, $

$\phi(m) = 8190 \cdot  65536$

$d = 201934721$

I now want to decipher

$$\text{ARHILFKAODSTOSBSTWFQL}$$

Hint: The cypher text is given in blocks of length $7$, and every block represents a number in the "$26$-system" with $\text{A}$ representing $0$, $B$ representing $1$ and so on. The clear message does have blocks of length $6$ then.

In class, we started out with

$$c_1 = 0 \cdot 26^6 + 17 \cdot 26^5 + 7 \cdot 26^4 + 8 \cdot 26^3 + 11 \cdot 26^2 + 5 \cdot 26 + 10.$$

Then, we tried to determine

$$c_1^d \equiv 20002966 \mod m,$$

but I don't know why and how it happened.

The clear message is supposed to be "BRUCEWAYNEISBATMAN".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should break it up in blocks of $7$, only you should check that the result of decoding the string to a number is $<m$.

In this case it does hold, decoding `ARHILFK` gives $c_1=205330408$, `AODSTOS` gives $c_2 = 168039786$ and finally `BSTWFQL` decodes as $c_3 = 531853567$ all of which are $<m$ indeed. (decoding done in Python, not very hard).

Now raising these to power $d$ modulo $m$ gives $p_1 = 20002966$, $p_2 = 11198842$ and $p_3 = 12223445$. Now encode these numbers as strings again: for $p_1$ we find the largest multiple (by a number $\le 25$) power of $26$ that is smaller or equal than $p_1$ and this is $1\cdot 26^5$, so the leftmost letter becomes $B$ (which corresponds to $1$). Substract that from $p_1$ and we are left with $8121590$. We can divide thus by $26^4$ $17$ times, with remainder $352998$. So the next letter is `R` (from $17$) and we go to $26^3$: $352998  =20\cdot 26^3 + 1478$ so we write down `U` (for $20$) and then $1478 = 2\cdot 26^2 + 126$ so we get `C` and finally $126 = 4 \cdot 26^1 + 22$ so the last two letters are `E` and `W`. So indeed `BRUCEW` is the plaintext. Note that this is 6 letters, instead of 7, but we could have used `BRUCEWA` which becomes the number $520077116 < m$, it's just on the limit. Stricly speaking we would have to decode as `ABRUCEW` and $p_2$ becomes `AAYNEIS` and $p_3$ becomes `ABATMAN`.

The initial `A` must then be discarded, seemingly. So maybe the plaintext should be divided up into groups of $6$ and for the output we need $6$ or $7$.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two errors. First: Your decoding of `ARHILFK` should be $\;\dots 5\cdot 26 + 10,$ but this is minor.  Second and severe: You **cannot** use blocks of length 7 because 
$$26^7-1 = 8031810175 > m,$$ and therefore you cannot recover a valid plain text. I guess your ciphertext is computed with this invalid block length.

Using block length 6, the plaintext would be encoded as

```
p = "BRUCEW" = 1*26^5 + 17*26^4 + 20*26^3 + 2*26^2 + 4*26^1 + 22 = 20002966
```

and then $c=p^e \bmod m = 205330408.$ This would be encoded as `RHILFK` (looks familiar, only the leading `A` is dropped from your text) and then
$c^d \bmod m = 20002966$, and the starting plaintext is recovered.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! There might be an error in the translation, but "given in blocks of length 7" should come really close to it. At least that's the way it's written in the excercise.